# is it normal that the array is not modified

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

Is it normal that

```
object.array.push('xxx');
```

does not apply the changes to the array, but it applies changes to objects?

I thought arrays were objects in javascript?!

I'm using the getGlobal function from the remote module https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/remote.md and changes are not applied to arrays

complete code- main.js:

```
global.data = {
  items: ['aaa', 'bbb']
};
```

in renderer.js

```
remote.getGlobal('data').items.push('xxx');
console.log(remote.getGlobal('data').items); <- no xxx
```

Comment: [I promise it changes the array.](https://jsfiddle.net/xzvvLvmo/) Can you give us some example code which exhibits the bug?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here, do you have a running example that shows your issue?

Comment: If you could provide a code example showing what you are talking about and what result you actually expected, it would be quite helpful.

Comment: my real code is `remote.getGlobal('data').items.push('xxx');` and if I do after that console.log() for my data global variable I see it unchanged

Comment: That just prompts us to ask: What does `getGlobal('data')` do? So as the others said above, please post a [mcve] demonstrating the problem. Note the "minimal," but note also the "complete" (e.g., it must be something that runs and actually demonstrates the problem). Yes, arrays are objects, and yes, `push` does modify the array you call it on. So either `items` isn't an array, or its `push` has been overridden, or you're looking at a *different* array later, not the one you called `push` on. Etc.

Comment: you are changing the `items` property not what you get from `remote.getGlobal('data')`.

Comment: So that probably means `remote.getGlobal('data')` returns a new copy, not the same reference....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/remote.md):

> **Note:** Arrays and Buffers are copied over IPC when accessed via the `remote` module. Modifying them in the renderer process does not modify them in the main process and vice versa.

Comment: man javascript is full of surprises :/

Comment: @thelolcat It's not a JavaScript thing, really. It's just how inter-process communication has to work unless a shared memory implementation is used. Shared memory is pretty much impossible in JS since it lacks any concurrency primitives (for now).

Comment: this is obviously racist because array is object, and object works but array not